# XCopy with special characters

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, characters

The xcopy in my batch file is not copying the special chars correctly.  The Š is turned into a è.  There are other funny chars that are changed as well.

This is the command in the batch file:

```
dir "\\USATL02ERAS40\auditfiles\Loblaws\LCL_2016\Z-DT\NDS 2016\LCL SUPPLIED 2016\*.xls*" /A /B /S > XLSVndDir1.tx
```

This is the file name:

```
1027948_16356344_wk 35 @NIVEA BODY@48965 Body 625ml 77240 CrŠme  Soft 250-200ml 24253 Inshower @ AD @ $0 30 $0 50 $0 05 @ RCWC EF_VS.xlsm
```

This is the output in my text file:

```
1027948_16356344_wk 35 @NIVEA BODY@48965 Body 625ml 77240 Crème  Soft 250-200ml 24253 Inshower @ AD @ $0 30 $0 50 $0 05 @ RCWC EF_VS.xlsm
```

How do I get the correct name with the special chars?

Comment: If you use `type` to view the outputted text fie in the command prompt, which character is shown (Š or è)?

Comment: What does `xcopy` have to do with your problem? Your batch file is using `dir`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant dir, not xcopy.

Comment: Please edit your question with the correct information.

Answer (score 0):

Flagrant [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case.

Encoding of a target file of [`>` redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) in Windows command line strictly depends on (and defaults to) *active code page* (unless in `cmd /U`).

Example:

```
==> dir /b /S ".\files\1207235\*.txt"
d:\bat\files\1207235\Crème.txt

==> del 1207235log.txt

==> chcp 437
Active code page: 437

==> >>1207235log.txt dir /b /S ".\files\1207235\*.txt"

==> chcp 1252
Active code page: 1252

==> >>1207235log.txt dir /b /S ".\files\1207235\*.txt"

==>
==> type 1207235log.txt
d:\bat\files\1207235\CrŠme.txt
d:\bat\files\1207235\Crème.txt

==> chcp 437
Active code page: 437

==> type 1207235log.txt
d:\bat\files\1207235\Crème.txt
d:\bat\files\1207235\CrΦme.txt

==>
```